# In javascript can function`s name be its argument?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I came across this example code.
    `function shippingFee(shippingFee) {
        //somecode
     }`

And I am unable to understand how this works and what is this phenomenon called in programming when you pass a function`s name as its value.

Comment: Yes, you can use the function name as an argument name, but that argument shadows the reference to the function itself within the function body.

Comment: It's quite similar to what happens when you do `function shippingFee() { var shippingFee; /* some code */ }`